# WSL2 Ubuntu system out of Space with /init tools Filesystem

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the WSL2 Ubuntu on my windows system and right now is out of space. But I could not find where is the space are using on my Ubuntu. It shows I'm only using 32G on my /dev/sdb which is correct. I have around 30G of the files and data on Ubuntu. However, I found there is a 98% usage on tools which is mounted on /init. How can I release those space?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJIUU.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are out of space on your `C:` drive in Windows.

Ubuntu on WSL2 lives in a virtual disk that, by default, resides on the Windows `C:` drive.  The virtual drive itself (which is mounted as `/dev/sdb` in your case) is allocated with 256GB available *to Ubuntu*.
On the Windows drive, however, the *file* for the virtual disk (`ext4.vhdx) starts just large enough to accommodate the files in your Ubuntu/ext4 filesystem, then *grows* as needed on the Windows drive as you add files.

Note, however, that the virtual disk does not (currently) automatically *shrink* when you remove files from Ubuntu.

Of course, it can only grow as as large as the available free space you have on your `C:` drive.

On the other hand, `/init` actually *does* live on the Windows drive itself, so what you see there is the space available on `C:`.  The "Used" in that case are *all files on `C:`, and there's not a whole lot you can do about it from *inside Ubuntu/WSL2*.

From your screenshot ([please don't do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) ;-)), you have:

- A 221G `C:` partition
- ~ 216G in use on that partition.  That amount includes the 32GB being used by Ubuntu.
- ~ 5.3GB remaining on `C:`.  That can be consumed by either Windows files or (through the virtual disk growing) Ubuntu files.

So really, with 22GB being used in Ubuntu, but another 194GB being used in Windows, the best thing you can do is clear space in Windows (delete temp files, clear out old downloads, etc.).

If you have another, larger drive or partition in Windows, you can also move Ubuntu's virtual disk to a location on that drive.  Depending on how much you use Ubuntu, I'd recommend that the drive be at least as fast the `C:` drive, of course.  Moving it from an SDD to an HDD will, of course, cause a performance decrease.

To move it, stop everything in Ubuntu, then go to PowerShell and:

```
mkdir D:\WSL\images # For example
mkdir D:\WSL\instances\<newDistroName>
cd D:\WSL
    
wsl -l -v # Verify distro name to export
wsl --terminate <distroname>
wsl --export <distroname> .\images\<distroname>.tar
wsl --import <newDistroName> .\instances\<newDistroName> .\images\<distroname>.tar
wsl ~ -d <newDistroName>
```

You'll also need to set the default username in that copied instance via the `/etc/wsl.conf` file as discussed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).

After confirming that the new instance works as expected and has all your files, you can set it as the default via (also from PowerShell):

```
wsl --set-default <newDistroName>
```

Then uninstall the "Ubuntu" app by right-clicking on it in the Windows Start menu and selecting *"Uninstall"*.  This, of course, is a  destructive operation that will remove all of the previous Ubuntu installation from the `C:` drive.

You can either keep the `D:\WSL\instances\<distroname>.tar` file as a backup (depending on your free space situation on `D:` (or other drive) or remove it.